# From a bag containing $10$ pairs of socks, how many must a person pull out to ensure that they get at least $2$ matching pairs of socks?

Tags: combinatorics

> There are $10$ pairs of socks in bag.  What is the minimum number of socks that a person should pull out from the bag to ensure that they get at least $2$ matching pairs of socks.

Comment: Worse case scenario with 2 to 10 draws is all unmatched socks. What happens on the 11th draw? and 12th?

Comment: Get yourself a bag of socks and start pulling them out.

Comment: This type of problem is solvable via the so called pigeonhole principle.

Comment: thanks! for the suggestion

Answer (score 4):

Divide the socks into two groups: left and right ones. There are $10$ in each. Pick $12$. By the extended pigeonhole principle you have picked at least two from each group, so you have two pairs. Less than $12$ clearly doesn't work, as you could be picking all from one group and one from the other.

Comment: what i think--- By the extended pigeonhole principle , the minimum number of socks that a person should pull out from the bag to ensure that they get at least 2 matching pairs of socks is 3.